Creating a toggle button to show/hide help text in a QGIS Plugin using Qt Designer
I am trying to create a QGIS plugin with Qt Designer that includes a button to show and hide text on the left of the window. The button should toggle between showing and hiding a label containing text, similar to the default behavior in QGIS windows. This button is commonly used in most QGIS operations (in this case, I have attached the window for Vector Clipping). I do not know which widget box to use in Qt Designer. I initially tried using the QgsCollapsibleGroupBox but I'm not sure if it is the right choice (see the second image). It does not look good.



I found the implementation of the 'collapsible info widget' in the QGIS GitHub Repository (Source).  From there it was relatively easy to rebuild using PyQt.
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QSplitter, QToolButton, QVBoxLayout, QWidget, QTextEdit
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QByteArray


class CollapsableSplitterWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        # state variables
        self.mHelpCollapsed = False
        self.mSplitterState = QByteArray()

        # ceate a splitter and add two widgets
        self.splitter = QSplitter(Qt.Horizontal)
        text_edit1 = QTextEdit("Text")
        text_edit2 = QTextEdit("Hello")
        self.splitter.addWidget(text_edit1)
        self.splitter.addWidget(text_edit2)

        self.splitter.setHandleWidth(20)
        
        #only second widget is collapsable
        self.splitter.setCollapsible(0, False)

        # get the splitter handle
        splitter_handle = self.splitter.handle(1)

        # create a layout for the handle
        handle_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        handle_layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)

        # create the collapse button
        self.button_collapse = QToolButton(splitter_handle)
        self.button_collapse.setAutoRaise(True)
        self.button_collapse.setFixedSize(12, 12)
        self.button_collapse.setCursor(Qt.ArrowCursor)
        self.button_collapse.setArrowType(Qt.RightArrow)

        # add collapse button to the handle layout
        handle_layout.addWidget(self.button_collapse)
        handle_layout.addStretch()

        # Set the layout to the splitter handle
        splitter_handle.setLayout(handle_layout)

        # Connect the toggleCollapsed function to the button click signal
        self.button_collapse.clicked.connect(self.toggleCollapsed)

        # track spliiter state to set the correct arrow
        self.splitter.splitterMoved.connect(self.splitterChanged)

        self.setCentralWidget(self.splitter)
        

    def toggleCollapsed(self):
        if self.mHelpCollapsed:
            self.splitter.restoreState(self.mSplitterState)
            self.button_collapse.setArrowType(Qt.RightArrow)
        else:
            self.mSplitterState = self.splitter.saveState()
            self.splitter.setSizes([1, 0])
            self.button_collapse.setArrowType(Qt.LeftArrow)

        # Toggle the collapsed state
        self.mHelpCollapsed = not self.mHelpCollapsed

    def splitterChanged(self, pos, index):
        if self.splitter.sizes()[1] == 0:
            self.mHelpCollapsed = True
            self.button_collapse.setArrowType(Qt.LeftArrow)
        else:
            self.mHelpCollapsed = False
            self.button_collapse.setArrowType(Qt.RightArrow)



window = CollapsableSplitterWindow()
window.show()


To test it, simply paste the code snippet in the PyQGIS console. This is the result:


Unfortunately, you cannot rebuild the entire ui as shown here in qt designer. the splitter handle, to which i add the collapse button, can only be accessed via PyQt.

It is possible to add custom widgets written in python to Designer. Also, I would suggest inheriting your splitter class from QWidget instead of QMainWindow. That way, you can add it to a dialog, main window, or position it within a layout.

It worked out! Regarding the answer by juto96, I would also like to add the following point: I think I also need  to exclude the code " - FORM_CLASS, _ = uic.loadUiType(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(file), '_dialog_base.ui'))" which is included in plugin_dialog.py (not in the above question I asked above but in the same directory). Instead, I should import directly the above .py file. Am I right?
